# How to add buttons or clickable text to the lock screen in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, lockscreen

I am developing an iOS app and one requirement of the app is that the user has to be able to interact with the app through buttons or clickable text on the lock screen. A minimum of 5 and a maximum of 8 buttons are to be shown to the user on the lock screen.

Please suggest what I can use to add this feature to the application.

Comment: You can't have a button or text be persistently on the lock screen all the time in iOS, but you can send the user notifications that do things along the lines of what it sounds like you're talking about: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot add controls of any kind to the lock screen in iOS. However, one option that might work for you is a today extension. Today extensions are accessible from the lock screen if enabled by the user.

Apple Docs on Today Extension:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html

Here’s a good tutorial on how to build a Today Extension:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/150953/today-extension-tutorial-getting-started